# How to dynamically filter data base on category property ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter data based on categories but have encountered some difficulties.
I want to have a list of items that represent the categories on the side and on the other side all of the items. When the users click on the specific categories only the items that have that particular category should be rendered.
Here is what I have so far: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-goodall-8trmbs?file=/src/App.js)
The first problem I have encountered is that in the data file are more items with the same categories, and if I map through them, the same categories would show multiple times.

The second problem is that I cannot figure out how I could render only the selected categories. I would like to achieve this without a selection and the use of e.target.value.

Forward on I would like for the user to be able to select multiple categories at once and also to be able to deselect all of them.

Please let me know if my approach is current and if I need to restructure my data. Also, I would appreciate it if you could link the responses to some threads that are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function which will return unique catergory as:

```
function getUniqueCategory(books) {
    const set = new Set();
    return books.filter((o) => {
        return set.has(o.category) ? false : (set.add(o.category), true);
    });
}
```

[`CODESANDBOX DEMO`](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-voice-y7gicj?file=/src/App.js)

and `onClick` of `category` you can pass `listItem` as:

```
onClick={() => sortList(listItem)}>
```

and Filter list as:

```
const sortList = (listItem) => {
    console.log(listItem);

    const categoryGroup = books.filter((obj) => {
        return obj.category === listItem.category;
    });

    setFilteredList(categoryGroup);
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to have more categories active at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by more categories at the same time

Comment: For example, both Action and Crime categories to be rendered after selecting both

Comment: You can check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-river-z8n24o?file=/src/App.js) where you can select/deselect category on click of a category. And you can select multiple category also.

Comment: Thank you very much, really! I appreciated that you actually provided the code. Much love!